# If Cell full Write Text to Next Cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

How, in VBA with Excel, can you check if a cell has text in it, and write something to the cell below if it does (infinite times)? I've tried to do this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
  Sheet2.Range("A").Value = Sheet1.TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

This just seems to change the whole A column. I want the Text Box on Sheet1 to write its text to the first blank cell in 'Column A' on Sheet2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the Text Box on Sheet1 to write its text to the first blank cell in 'Column A' on Sheet2.

If you want to find last non empty cell and then write your value in the next cell, use this code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
   Dim lastrow As Long
   With Sheet2
       lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       .Range("A" & lastrow + _
            IIf(lastrow = 1 And .Range("A1") = "", 0, 1)).Value _
        = Sheet1.TextBox1.Value
   End With
End Sub
```

if you want to find *first* empty cell in column `A`, (i.e. if you have data in `A1`, `A2`, `A4`, but not in `A3`, then *first* empty cell would be `A3`) use this code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim emptyRow As Long
    With Sheet2
        emptyRow = IIf( _
           .Range("A1") = "", 1, _
           IIf(.Range("A2") = "", 2, _
               Application.Min(.Cells(1, "A").End(xlDown).Row + 1, Rows.count)))
        .Range("A" & emptyRow).Value = "S"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: After the first time I click the button, it gives me an error. The first time it sets the cell to the text, then says: .Range("A" & emptyRow).Value = <Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed>  -and- emptyRow = 1048577

Comment: Updated my asnwer. Try now. Btw, what code do you use, first or second?